# Skip the gitlab cicd pipeline from execution if new branch has no other changes than main

Tags: gitlab, yaml, devops, cicd

My program structure looks something like this

[image]

Here is my yaml file

```
folder-a:
  tags:
    - main-runner
  stage:
    build-a
  script:
    - echo "folder-a"
  only:
    changes:
      - a/**

folder-b:
  tags:
    - main-runner
  stage:
    build-b
  script:
    - echo "folder-b"
  only:
    changes:
      - b/**
```

whenever there is change in either folder-a or folder-b the script will execute

Problem is - when I create a new branch from main branch, its as if that both folder-a and folder-b has changes and the cicd pipeline runs.

But I dont want it to happen. What I want is
1] When a new branch is created, it should diff with main branch and if its exactly same as main branch, the cicd pipeline will not run
2] If new branch is created on gitlab with some changes that are ahead of main(creating local branch and pushing to remote) yml will check which folder got changes folder-a/b or both and run the yml accordingly

Comment: I guess you can compare the HEAD SHA with the BASE SHA and check if they're different...

Comment: In github we can do [this](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/.github/workflows/pull-request.yml#L34), so I guess in GitLab there'll be something similar